# Как использовать прокси с Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Сайт парсит контент с определенного донор-сайта через CURL.
В данный момент блокировка по IP с этого сайта. Поставил CURL_PROXY. Работают только страницы, которые не используют Symfony, а на Symfony следующая ошибkа:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Expecting a DOMNodeList or
>        DOMNode instance, an array, a string, or null, but got "boolean". in
>       /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php:120 Stack trace:
>        #0 /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php(67):
>       Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->add(false) #1
>       /var/www/user/data/www/site/controllers/st.php(49):
>       Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->__construct(false, 'https://site.ru...')
>        #2 /var/www/user/data/www/site/content/index.php(50):
>       require_once('/var/www/user/d...') #3 {main} thrown in
>       /var/www/user/data/www/site/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php on line 120

В коде:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

// links
$dom = new Crawler($response, 'https://site.ru/dir/');

foreach ($dom->filter('#main div a.t-block_item') as $node)
{
    $name = trim($node->textContent);
    $uri = str_replace('https://site.ru/dir/', null, $node->getAttribute('href'));
    $uri = preg_replace_callback('%[^:@/?#&=\.]+%usD', function ($matches) {
        return urlencode($matches[0]);
    }, $uri);

    $arr['dir'][] = [
        'url' => implode('/', array_map('urldecode', explode('/', parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH)))),
        'urlName' => $name
    ];
}
```

До блокировки по IP, всё прекрасно работало и на Symfony.

Как на нем использовать прокси?

Comment: Вы передаёте в контроллер false, вместо строки.  Откуда у вас берётся `$response`? Вероятно из `curl_exec`. Ваш запрос не проходит, смотрите ошибки курла, чтобы понять почему.

Comment: Дак в том то и дело, что response $response = class::getPage($requestUrl, 'https://site.ru'); он не может получить сайт site.ru из-за бан по IP с этого сайта. Я поставил в curl прокси, всё заработало, только в обычных страницах, а проблемы с Symfony

Comment: @Webmaster что за `class::getPage`? Что у него внутри? Сейчас он возвращает `false` и `Crawler` тут не при чём.

Comment: Запустите отладку и посмотрите в чём дело, пошагово